# How do I read all dates between start date and end date in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to read all dates between two range of dates and this ranges includes both start date and end date

```
 input_start_date="2013-09-05"
 input_end_date="2013-09-10"

 START_DATE=$(date -I -d "$input_start_date") || exit -1
 END_DATE=$(date -I -d "$input_end_date")     || exit -1

 d="$START_DATE"
 while [ "$d" <= "$END_DATE" ]; do 
  echo $d
   d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
 done
```

but when I ran the above code  I get below error

```
 bash: = 2013-09-10: No such file or directory
```

Could someone help me to fix this issue

Expected output

```
  2013-09-05
  2013-09-06
  2013-09-07
  2013-09-08
  2013-09-09
  2013-09-10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is right, but you just got the operator wrong, `<=` does not work with `date` strings in `bash`, you needed a inequality operator `!=` in the condition.

```
while [ "$d" != "$enddate" ]; do
```

The `<=` operator works when used in arithmetic context in `bash` with the `((..))` operator.

Answer (score 5):

```
start=2013-09-05
end=2013-09-10
   while [[ $start < $end ]] 
     do 
      printf "$start\n"; start=$(date -d "$start + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d") 
     done
```

or you can try this one

```
END=$(date -d "2013-09-10" +%s);
DATE=$(date -d "2013-09-05" +%s); 
while [[ "$DATE" -le "$END" ]]; do date -d "@$DATE" +%F; let DATE+=86400; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Something little in awk (changed the range a bit since there was no test data, just the expected output):

```
$ awk '$0>="2013-09-06" && $0<="2013-09-09"' file
2013-09-06
2013-09-07
2013-09-08
2013-09-09
```

Answer (score 1):

You kind of need a do-while loop here, which bash does not provide. How about

```
date="$start_date"
while true; do 
    echo "$date"
    [[ $date = "$end_date" ]] && break
    date=$(date -d "$date + 1 day" "+%F")
done
```

Don't use ALL_CAPS_VAR_NAMES -- too easy to mistakenly overwrite shell/system vars.